# What is wrong with my solution for GBM?

Tags: calculus

I treid to solve the SDE(GBM)

$dS_t = μS_tdt + σS_tdW_t$

Devide it with $S_t$ then, $\frac{1}{S_t}dS_t = μdt + σdW_t$

Integrate from time 0 to time t then, $∫^t_0\frac{1}{S_u}dS_u = μ∫^t_0du + σ∫^t_0dW_u$

Because the diffusion term : $σ∫^t_0dW_u$ is not the form such as $∫^t_0W_tdW_u$ In the end I think it is not stochastic calculus, just apply ordinary calculus.. like this $[W_u]^t_0$.

So I think we can apply fundamental theorem of the calculus. I mean,
$∫^t_0\frac{1}{S_u}dS_u = μ∫^t_0du + σ∫^t_0dW_u$ So,
$lnS_t-lnS_0=μ(t-0)+ σ(W_t-W_0)$

And make it exponential form,
$\frac{S_t}{S_0}=e^{μt+σW_t}$
Therefore, $S_t=S_0*e^{μt+σW_t}$

But It is not the answer.

Of course, using Ito's formula I can derive the solution : $S_t=S_0*e^{(μ-\frac{σ^2}{2})t+σW_t}$ However, I think I made no mistakes. What makes me in trouble?

Comment: Your problem is the evaluation of the Ito integral $\int_0^t \frac1{S_u}\,dS_u$.  It's not just $\ln(S_t)-\ln(S_0)$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring But when I consider this video, $Var(dS_t) = σ^2(S_t)^2Var(dW_t)$. I think it means $S_t$ is considered as constants. So $∫^t_0\frac{1}{S_u}dS_u$ is $ln(S_t)−ln(S_0)$. The link of my reference video is like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErBg6qQUju4&t=742s

Comment: If $S_u$ is need to be evaluated with Ito integral, then what is the reason that $S_t$ is work as constant so make the variance like this : $Var(dS_t) = σ^2(S_t)^2Var(dW_t)$?

Comment: If my confusion, in the above reply, is cleared, then It seems I can totally agree with your reply.

Comment: Where does the video say $\operatorname{Var}(dS_t) = \sigma^2S_t^2\operatorname{Var}(dW_t)$?  Even if I grant the somewhat dubious notation for the differential of the quadratic variation, your timestamp leads me to a point where the closest equation to yours is $$\operatorname{Var}(dS_t \mid \mathcal{F}_t) = \sigma^2S_t^2\operatorname{Var}(dW_t \mid \mathcal{F}_t)$$ which are conditional variances, hence random.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sorry for missing timestamp. The time in the video is 11:48. And your guess for equation is right : $Var(dS_t∣F_t)=σ^2S^2_tVar(dW_t∣F_t)$. I mean if $S_t$ is treated as random, then the equation need to be $Var(dS_t∣F_t)=σ^2Var(S^2_tdW_t∣F_t)$. That is the $S^2_t$ need to be inside of $Var()$ not outside of it. That's my confusing point.

Comment: Oh.. Is it because the Filteration's time subscript 't' is same with $S^2_t$, that makes $S^2_t$ be treated as constant? Then now my confusion is solved. Thanks a lot.